# What is the difference between "~/" and "../"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In code I often find ~/ or ../ with paths but unfortunately it is not clear to me what these are and what the difference is. Which one to use with multiple level directories ?

I guess ../ means domain of site or application?

Can you please guide what they are, and how they are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde (~) refers to the application root directory. In ASP, the tilde is used for HyperLinks or Page.ResolveURL.

Two dots (..) refers to the folder that is one level higher than the current folder.

Comment: Thanks @CC Inc, 

"Two dots (..) refers to the folder that is one level higher than the current folder."

By Current folder do you mean the folder in which currently code is executed ?

Can we also use ../../NewPageName.aspx  ?

Comment: @user576510 Yes, by current folder I mean where the code is executed, and that should be a valid path.

Comment: Can we also use ../../   ?

Comment: @user576510 What do you mean? You could but I dont see much use in that.

Comment: I didn't see much too in .NET framework. However, I have seen this repeatedly in some raw development. Because there is not specific asset folders are available therefore it urges them to use `../../` again and again.

Answer (score 7):

`~/` is often refereed to in helper functions such as `<%= ResolveUrl() %>` for example. It refers to the root of the website whereas `../` simply refers to the parent directory. Both are relative urls.

Let's take an example. Suppose that your website is hosted in a virtual directory called `MyApplication`. When you use `<%= ResolveUrl("~/foo/bar") %>` it would generate `/MyApplication/foo/bar` as output url and this no matter in which WebForm location.

Answer (score 5):

There're two kinds of paths:

- Regular paths
- Virtual paths

When you just use `/` or `../` you're using regular paths relative to the IIS - the web server - Web site URL. That is, `/myfile.txt` would be wrong if your application is hosted in a virtual directory called `mydir`. In this case, `/myfile.txt` will end in an URL like this: `http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.txt`, while you expected `http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/myfile.txt`.

For that reason, ASP.NET gives you the chance to provide virtual paths. All of them start with `~` character. The `~` character specifies that the resolved URI is relative to the IIS application. Taking the above example of expecting `http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/myfile.txt`, the right virtual path would be `~/myfile.txt`.

**Note that virtual paths aren't allowed in non-server controls. This kind of path is used in a selected number of ASP.NET class methods and server controls**.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned "Virtual Paths are only in server cont4rols" just one thing please. For non server side controls /client side controls or scripts is there a way ?

Comment: Good explanation, ok virtual directory means `http://www.example.com/mydir/myfile.txt` what does `http://www.example.com/` mean ?, root directory , isn't ?